# iOS - find out a view's constraints at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, constraints

How do I find an object's TRUE `frame` at runtime when using Autolayout + Constraints?

I have a `UIButton` constrained to the screen's upper right-hand corner. 
But when I log out this Button's `frame` at runtime (in `viewDidLoad`) I'm told its `x` value is 500 - which of course isn't accurate (if it were, the button would be way off screen.)
But since I'm using Constraints, the button is not offscreen, its tucked nicely in the upper right-hand corner, the way it should be.

So I'm trying to find out what its true `x` value is.

*Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is this: the user needs to be able to drag this object away, and at some point the App needs to animate the object ***back*** to its original position.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: The frame of a view is relative to its parent so 500 might be correct depending on your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to NSLog the frame not in the viewDidLoad but viewDidLayoutSubviews. Autolayout does not layout subviews to fit to the screen in viewDidLoad.

Comment: oh man - that was obvious :-)  Biggest "DUH!!!" of the day. Can you tell its past 11:00pm? I'm obviously brain dead and should really hit the sack and call it quits for the day.  Either way: Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try logging the constraints in the method viewDidAppear().